# GET Request to RestfulAPI from Visual Basic with Body

Tags: vba, restful-url

SO, below is the code on my Restful API. It is working in Postman completely fine.

I am wanting to send a request to the API with the body containing `{"email_address":"a@gmail.com"}` but can't figure out how to do that in Visual Basic. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import boto3
import json

users = ["a@hotmail.com", "b@hotmail.com"]

def respond(res):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(res),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = event['body'] 
    email_address = json.loads(body)['email_address']
    if email_address in users:
        response = "Authorised"
        return respond(response)
    else:
        response = "NotAuthorised"
        return respond(response)
```

It is working in Python with the below code:

```
import requests
x = requests.request(method='get', url='APIURL', data='{"email_address":"a@hotmail.com"}')
x.json()
```

Guess I just need some help converting it to Visual Basic.

Comment: Did you try googling for (eg) "VBA post JSON" ?   You should get plenty of examples.

Comment: As the server will accept a JSON string I anticipate this should be easy to google and write. `data` will be what you POST. It is a little odd to see `data` against `GET` in your existing code. I believe is one of the optional params however.